QGIS doesn't show network drive directories
Today QGIS wouldn't let me open up without starting it as an administrator, after doing that the drives from our company server were not shown anymore and the local ones C: and D: had a lock attached to them.
Main problem is that is not possible to drag and drop shp-files etc. to QGIS and I always have to use the full UNC-path server name to even open up projects. //ServerName/Vol/Q for example works, but not only Q:. Everywhere outside of QGIS the drives work fine, I already reinstalled multiple availabe versions, but always get the same error. Currently I am using 3.34.12.
